# !important style attribute override not working

Tags: css

I am having a problem making my  element red while applying two classes to it with the '!important' function. Its for an exercise on a programming course. Any help would be greatly appreciated. My code is as follows.

```html
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style>
  .red-text {
    color: red;
  }
  
  .urgently-red {
    font-color: red !important;
  }
  
  .blue-text {
    font-color: blue;
  }

  h2 {
    font-family: Lobster, Monospace;
  }

  p {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Monospace;
  }
</style>

<h2 class='urgently-red blue-text'>CatPhotoApp</h2>

<p class='red-text'>Kitty ipsum dolor sit amet, shed everywhere shed everywhere stretching attack your ankles chase the red dot, hairball run catnip eat the grass sniff.</p>
<p class='red-text'>Purr jump eat the grass rip the couch scratched sunbathe, shed everywhere rip the couch sleep in the sink fluffy fur catnip scratched.</p>
```

Comment: `font-color` is not valid, change it to simply `color`. If you put `.urgently-red` after `.blue-text` it should take precedence.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
  .red-text {
    color: red;
  }

  .urgently-red {
    font-color: red !important;
  }

  .blue-text {
    font-color: blue;
  }

  h2 {
    font-family: Lobster, Monospace;
  }

  p {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Monospace;
  }
```

With

```
 .red-text {
    color: red;
  }

  .urgently-red {
    color: red !important;
  }

  .blue-text {
    color: blue;
  }

  h2 {
    font-family: Lobster, Monospace;
  }

  p {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Monospace;
  }
```

Changes: `font-color` to `color`

Comment: Ah, it threw me off because on the course it ticked off that part as if I had done it correctly. Thank you, I knew it would be a simple fix.